# having run-time 1004 error in autofill method for a single data point range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a run-time error in this section of my code.
This is how I define my dynamic range :

```
Fulfillment_Status='0_DeliveryDateOrders'!$J$2:INDEX('0_DeliveryDateOrders'!$J$2:$J$100000,COUNTA('0_DeliveryDateOrders'!$I$2:$I$100000),0)
```

Weird thing is, I have this error when I have only 1 row of data at Fulfillmet_status range, what it means , I am having this error when the data is only in J2 cell. Is there any workaround to avoid this?

```
   Range("J2").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""unfulfilled"""
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Fulfillment_Status")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, in fact? To copy "=unfulfilled" in the range defined by "Fulfillment_Status" named range? If you try `Debug.Print Range("Fulfillment_Status").Address(external:=True)`, what does it return? When you try selecting the named range from `Name Box`, does it select the range you like to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem comes from the fact that you try to fill a range starting from active sheet `Range("J2")` up to a sheet "0_DeliveryDateOrders" named range, which is not possible. Try, please:

```
Range("Fulfillment_Status").Parent.Range("J2").Formula = "=""unfulfilled"""
  Range("Fulfillment_Status").Parent.Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Fulfillment_Status")
```

It will extract the necessary sheet from the named range and use it independent of the active sheet.

But, if you need/want to make the auto filling in the active sheet based on the named range address, it is possible, but in a different way. If you want that, please state it and I will edit the answer and show another variant for such a case.

Comment: @Cagdas Kanar Didn't the above way solve your problem?